# Replace characters with asterisk

Tags: swift, string, replace, nsstring

I have this code from my playground.

I already have the userID and email extension separated. However I want to change the characters in between the first and last characters of the email with `*` except from `.`

I am trying to make it dynamic enough with any email address input. Any thoughts? Thank you for your input.

```
let email = "asdfg.hjkl@gmail.com"
let atSign = email.index(of: "@") ?? email.endIndex
let userID = email[..<atSign]
print(userID + email.suffix(from: atSign))
```

Comment: var newString = userID.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "*")

Comment: why not just like everyone else does this: `let obscuredEmail = email[email.startIndex..<email.index(email.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)] + String(repeating: "*", count: 12) + email[email.index(email.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)..<email.endIndex]` for instance?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however for this case I would want to have it a****.****l@gmail.com instead of asd************com as this would later be used on a different application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found an iterative solution:

```
let email = "asdfg.hjkl@gmail.com"
let atSign = email.index(of: "@") ?? email.endIndex
let userID = email[..<atSign]
print(userID + email.suffix(from: atSign))


var lastLetterInx = email.index(before:atSign)

var inx = email.startIndex

var result = ""
while(true) {
    if (inx >= lastLetterInx) {
        result.append(String(email[lastLetterInx...]))
        break;
    }

    if (inx > email.startIndex && email[inx] != ".") {
        result.append("*")      
    } else {
        result.append(email[inx])
    }

    inx = email.index(after:inx)
}

print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using Regular Expression, it's just one additional line

```
let email = "asdfg.hjkl@gmail.com"
let atSign = email.index(of: "@") ?? email.endIndex
let userID = email[..<atSign]
let hiddenUserID = userID.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?<!^)[^.]", with: "*", options: .regularExpression)
print(hiddenUserID + email.suffix(from: atSign)) // a****.****@gmail.com
```